# What's the measure of "Stop This Flame"?

Tags: analysis

I suppose Celeste's song is something like 2/4? It reminds me of samba.

Comment: It seems a normal 4/4 to me. Note that basic analysis questions ("in what key is this", "what is this rhythm", etc) are considered off topic for this website.